# How to use "3rd level of Caps Lock" as a compose key on Linux Mint 19.3 (based on Ubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to set up a convenient compose key to use for practicing Greek in duolingo. But, I don't want it to mess up my normal use of my laptop. I'm a developer by trade and use pretty much all of the normal single key options shown in the "Position of Compose key" settings in Linux regularly on my laptop, with the exception of the Menu key. However, my new laptop doesn't have a menu key. :-P

So, I wanted to try the "3rd level of Caps Lock" or any of the "3rd level" settings (see screenshot below for the settings I'm talking about).

[image]

But...having tried one, I'm not sure how to actually use it. I've tried searching, but all the info I've found about "3rd level keys" is when using a key as a modifier (e.g., holding Caps Lock and a simultaneously to get some modifier of a). That's not working though.

If I use one of these "3rd level of X" settings...how do I actually use it? :)

Comment: Funny you ask. I should update my question since I'm technically using Linux Mint Tessa (19.3) with Cinnamon. It's based on ubuntu 18.04. I believe the keyboard configuration is stock ubuntu though.

Comment: So it's off-topic here.

Comment: I wrote an answer before I saw that the question is off topic, and since I already wrote it, I decided to submit it. My answer ought to be generic and useful also for users of official Ubuntu, so you may want to edit your question again and exclude the info about Linux Mint to prevent that it gets hidden/deleted.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought the configuration UI was stock ubuntu, but perhaps not. I'll ask in Unix & Linux. Though thanks @GunnarHjalmarsson as your answer is still useful if I just end up using config files instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made an attempt at using <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> for the purpose, and even if I made it work, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> also kept doing its original thing, i.e. toggling to/from capital letters, which reasonably is not a desirable behavior.

So below I show how it can be done using "3rd level of Right Ctrl" instead.

On my Ubuntu 19.10 I run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:ralt_switch', 'compose:rctrl-altgr']"
```

The `lv3:ralt_switch` part defines the key to choose the 3rd level to <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> aka <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. For many keyboard layouts this is already done by default, and if so, that part can be excluded. For other keyboard layouts, with the basic *English (US)* as an example, the 3rd level key needs to be defined explicitly.

Then I can type for instance:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> followed by <kbd>0</kbd> followed by <kbd>C</kbd> => ©

Comment: Your feedback is useful regardless of distro. Thanks. :)